# Test case failure : Argument(s) are different! Wanted:

Tags: unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, mockito, junit4

I am  learning `JUnit` and `mockito`. I am trying to write test case for search filter from Account controller class. But I am getting `Argument(s) are different! Wanted:` failure . can any one tell me what I am doing wrong in Test case?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api.spacestudy.com/SpaceStudy/Admin")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accService;

    @GetMapping("/Account/findAccountData")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Tuple>> btnSearchClick(String sClientAcctId, String sAcctDesc, String sInvestigatorName,
            String sClientDeptId) throws Exception {
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.btnSearchClick("1124100", sAcctDesc,sInvestigatorName,sClientDeptId));
}
}
```

**Test case**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AccountControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void btnSearchClickTest() throws Exception {

        String sClientAcctId = "1124100";
        String sAcctDesc = "SRIRAM";
        String sInvestigatorName = "Ram, Sri";
        String sClientDeptId = "120010";

        Tuple mockedTuple = Mockito.mock(Tuple.class);

        List<Tuple> accountObj = new ArrayList<>();
        accountObj.add(mockedTuple);

        Mockito.when(accountService.btnSearchClick(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId))
                .thenReturn(accountObj);

        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/api.spacestudy.com/SpaceStudy/Admin/Account/findAccountData").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());


        Mockito.verify(accountService).btnSearchClick(sClientAcctId, sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId);

    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
accountService.btnSearchClick(
    "1124100",
    "SRIRAM",
    "Ram, Sri",
    "120010"
);
-> at com.spacestudy.controller.AccountControllerTest.btnSearchClickTest(AccountControllerTest.java:110)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
accountService.btnSearchClick(
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
-> at com.spacestudy.controller.AccountController.btnSearchClick(AccountController.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone still has this problem, I got a working solution from [here](https://microeducate.tech/test-failure-message-in-mockito-arguments-are-different-wanted/)

Essentially, you just need to override the Object.equals(Object) in most cases and if that does not work, maybe because the object you are validating cannot be changed or its equals function can not be overriden (for whatever reason which is beyond the context of this post), then use `org.mockito.Matchers.refEq(T value, String... excludeFields)` like below:

```
verify(programServiceMock, times(1)).save(id, refEq(testpPList));
```